# IOS: View or container view

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

When should I either of these?
Which of these is better suited, if I only need to group sub-views and hide/ show them based on a logic?

Comment: view is best or easy to group subviews

Comment: Suggesting you to take a look at this post. [Container View]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355022/what-is-container-view-in-ios-5-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more clear with your question. From my understanding ...

When people talk about container views, they usually mean just a plain old UIView that contains other views. Using a view in that way lets you move all the views it contains as a group, so that their positions relative to each other are maintained. It also makes it easy to hide all the contained views as a group.

Adding subviews for small applications, will not consume much memory. While if you are going for huge applications, you must maintain a state, so that which view will be added to container view as subview at each state of your application.

**for example: 
 

state 1 - login 

state 2 - Dashboard 

state 3 - People VC**

Each state points to each viewController.  So you have to maintain a state machine for states and viewController in your application.