# How to get Multitasking between ViewControllers in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, multitasking

I'm developing an app that required to switch between viewcontrollers but without losing the current data when multitasking !

**My QUESTION :**

There is a Way to get something like UITabbarcontroller but with an animation (Multitasking) thanks to a Menu ?

Comment: This is default behaviour of UITabBarController. What are you doing that isn't working?

Comment: @Fogmeister i mentioned UITabBarController because of his behaviour (i mean if i write something inside a UITextfield it Remains when i switch and turn back to the same Viewcontroller)...**my Goal** get this behaviour when i don't have a UITabbarController so as to switch from 2 or more ViewControllers thanks to a Menu that i will create !

Comment: Ah I see. Well UItabBarController does this by keeping a handle (prob an array) of its view controllers. Then when you switch it just gets the VC out of the array instead of creating a new one. If you do this you will keep data at each VC.

Comment: What is "Multitasking", in your mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Container View but it will serve you better if you have to manage less Container Views. Doing that with all of your view controllers won't be a good idea. However with two or three Container Views you can keep the state of each view while you move forward and backward, plus you will have to perform the animations yourself, which I'm sure you will be able to do.

Here are a couple of links that will help you out with using Container View.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355022/what-is-container-view-in-ios-5-sdk)

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884879/how-to-use-a-container-view-in-ios)

Comment: Thanks I used Container View to Container a UITabbarController !